# Find array element that is true for ALL elements in the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the smallest common multiple from one array by comparing it to the values in the other by using `% num === 0`.  The answer should be 6, but because each number in the first array is true at least once, they all get returned. How do I find the value that is only true and never false?

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

function test(arr) {
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    for (let n of arr) {
        return x.filter(k => k % n === 0)
    }
}

console.log(test(arr))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need loop over the `x` array and return the first element that gets divided by [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) value in `arr`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

function test(arr) {
  let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  for (let n of x) {
    if (arr.every((a) => n % a === 0)) {
      return n;
    }
  }
}

console.log(test(arr));
```

You can also simply the solution using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const 
  arr = [1, 2, 3],
  test = (arr) =>
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].find((n) => arr.every((a) => n % a === 0));

console.log(test(arr));
```

**Note:** If `x` is *not* sorted, then you will have to sort it first.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3],
  test = (arr) =>
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
      .sort((a, b) => a - b)
      .find((n) => arr.every((a) => n % a === 0));

console.log(test(arr));
```

**Update based on OP's comment**

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3],
  test = (arr) =>
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].filter((n) => arr.some((a) => n / a === 2));

console.log(test(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I find all values of x that return 2 after dividing by at least one of the arr elements? So it would return 2, 4, 6. Setting the condition for ````n / a === 2```` returns undefined

Comment: @Qaqli Updated my answer, you can use `filter` and `some` now.

Comment: Awesome, I need to read up on these methods more, thank you!

Comment: I've added links to the documentation, you can reference them.

Answer (score 1):

Filter and intersect

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

function test(arr) {
  let common = []
  arr.forEach(n => common.push(x.filter(k => k % n === 0)))
  return common.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.filter(e => cur.includes(e)));
}


console.log(test(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

If x is sorted can use `find` and `every`

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12]

let res = x.find(n => arr.every(a => n%a === 0))
console.log(res)
```

if unsorted x

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let x = [1, 12, 6, 4, 2, 7, 8]

let res = [...x].sort((a,b)=> a-b).find(n => arr.every(a => n%a === 0))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Late to the party answer**

You could solved this with one line of code using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Here we initialize it with an empty array and then use a ternary operator to append values that pass the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) test. Note that we don't need to check for zero (c % n === 0) because we treat the result as a boolean.

```
x.reduce((p,c) => c % n ? p : p.concat([c]), [])
```

```js
// TEST

const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

[1, 2, 3].forEach(n => {

  console.log( 
     "n =" + n,
     x.reduce((p,c) => c % n ? p : p.concat([c]), [])
  );

});
```

Comment: I knew there was some magic reduce() operation that could solve this, thank you. Need to practice this method more.

Comment: Where is the "6" result?